# Trying to setup Node.js (Express) to work with vhosts, and getting unexpected errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vhosts

I'm trying to set it up to work with a couple vhosts, so that I could manage everything through the one node app; but I've been getting this error.

It's late right now, so my mind isn't 100%, but hopefully someone can see something I don't.

```
/vhosts/app.js:13
.listen(3000);
             ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
    at Module._compile (module.js:437:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

Here's the code:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app
.use(express.vhost('localhost', require('/first/vhost/app.js').app)
.use(express.vhost('localhost2', require('/second/vhost/app.js').app)
.listen(3000);
```

And that first vhost app runs fine, if I got and run it manually with `node app`.

Comment: You are missing a close bracket after each of your .use lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brett points out you are missing the last bracket:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app
.use(express.vhost('localhost', require('/first/vhost/app.js').app))
.use(express.vhost('localhost2', require('/second/vhost/app.js').app))
.listen(3000);
```

You should not use require inside the the Connect middleware. This way it would also have been easier to spot :-)

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var first = require('/first/vhost/app.js').app;
var second = require('/second/vhost/app.js').app;

app
.use(express.vhost('localhost', first))
.use(express.vhost('localhost2', second))
.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thanks - stupid mistake on my part. It definitely was the fact that I was super tired.